# Key binding to '?'

Tags: wpf, datagrid, key-bindings

I'm trying to add a keybinding onto a wpf datagrid when the user enters a '?' and have tried the following:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=OpenPrompt}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=CurrentCell}" Key="OemBackslash" Modifiers="Shift"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

i've also tried having the key set to 'Backslash' and 'Divide'.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acordding to [Key Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it's have to be `OemQuestion`

I tired it and it works:

```
 <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=CurrentCell}" Key="OemQuestion" Modifiers="Shift"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Perhaps you have a Binding problem?